# To get sunday's and saturday's date from a dataframe which has dates from Monday to tuesday

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe

```
    0
0   2022-07-25
1   2022-07-26
2   2022-07-27
3   2022-07-28
4   2022-07-29
```

this is from monday to tuesday . I need to add previous sunday date that is 2022-07-24 and saturday day 2022-07-23 into dataframe by calculating monday -1 and monday -2 likewise. please help

Comment: What do you mean by `by calculating monday -1 and monday -2` can you make ur question clear with the expected output please

Comment: I need  2022-07-24 in the dataframe(i.e previous sunday) and 2022-07-23 in the dataframme (i.e previous saturday)

Comment: why can't you just prepend those two values to the dataframe?

Comment: I am doing a project . So i need the dates in such a way.. I want user to only input dates from monday to friday

Comment: so your data lets say can have 30 values, and you want to fill all missing dates to it right?

Comment: No, User will give any dates from monday to friday. I will get it in a dataframe and I have to add previous sunday's date and saturday's date.

Comment: So for each row, I give you the previous saturday sunday for that day, would it be fine?

Comment: Hi Christopher, can you try my answer and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`pd.DateTime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) module to get the previous weekend date for each date in your column.

##### Creating the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-07-25','2022-07-26','2022-07-27','2022-07-28','2022-07-29']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

##### Calculate saturday and sunday dates

```
sat, sun = 5, 6
# Day of week for saturday : 5
df['Saturday_prev'] = df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['Date'].dt.dayofweek - sat)%7, unit='d')
# Day of week for Sunday : 6
df['Sunday_prev'] = df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['Date'].dt.dayofweek - sun)%7, unit='d')
```

##### Output :

This gives us the expected output :

```
        Date Saturday_prev Sunday_prev
0 2022-07-25    2022-07-23  2022-07-24
1 2022-07-26    2022-07-23  2022-07-24
2 2022-07-27    2022-07-23  2022-07-24
3 2022-07-28    2022-07-23  2022-07-24
4 2022-07-29    2022-07-23  2022-07-24
```

For a variety of dates, the program gives you expected output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-08-05','2022-08-10','2022-08-12','2022-08-21','2022-08-26']})
```

**Output** :

```
        Date Saturday_prev Sunday_prev
0 2022-08-05    2022-07-30  2022-07-31
1 2022-08-10    2022-08-06  2022-08-07
2 2022-08-12    2022-08-06  2022-08-07
3 2022-08-21    2022-08-20  2022-08-21
4 2022-08-26    2022-08-20  2022-08-21
```

Answer (score 0):

Himanshuman's answer is great, but I just wanted to show that using a dataframe for this problem really isn't necessary:

```
def get_saturday(input_date):
    date = pd.to_datetime(input_date)
    days_ago = (date.day_of_week - 5)%7
    return (date - pd.to_timedelta(days_ago, unit='d')).date()

user_input = '2022-07-28'
print(get_saturday(user_input))

# Output:
2022-07-23
```